Bronze Journal Bearing "Break-In" Period
I'm being told that the bronze journal bearing corresponding to a stainless steel shaft requires some time to "break in". Please note that these are used bearings that have been removed and installed into new bearing housings.
What is actually happening when a bearing like this one is being "broken in"? I'm not sure if I understand what could be causing initial temperatures to be higher than anticipated. I know that friction from the grease should be what causes the rise in temperature? Thank you in advance.

That seems a poor saving "used bearings that have been removed and installed into new bearing housings" given the likely cost of the new housings compared to new bearings...

I've never seen a journal bearing run on grease.

@SolarMike It was not my decision, and I agree to some extent.

@TigerGuy https://www.machinerylubrication.com/Read/779/journal-bearing-lubrication

@AdrianBeltran talk about bushings if you want to understand bushings.

@TigerGuy Per Google: "Sleeve bearings are also called bushings, journal bearings or plain bearings, and are the simplest design of bearing" I don't see where I used the wrong language.

@AdrianBeltran Out in the world, journal bearings are rotating shafts in journals supported by oil.  Which is why a question about them heating up doesn't make sense.  But you are fully approved to continue to ask questions however you want.
